# how to set the default directory in wix wpf setup "WIXUI_INSTALLDIR"

Tags: wpf, wix

i created the wix setup for the wpf application,issue is it is getting install and working for the given default path but it is not working when the use browse the another path. am using the "WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" and please go through the below code.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="Application name">
--bin files--
                </Directory>
           </Directory>
</Directory>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
            <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />

<SetDirectory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[WindowsVolume]Companyname\appplication name" />
```

It is working for the default path the mentioned above but not working if the user browse the another path.